# How to push notifications to all users together

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

I have been reading about push notifications but I am not getting it correctly. It says it can be used to send RSS feeds or personal messages etc, but that is 1-to-1 communication.

Can it be also used to send a message say "App update Available" to all the users who have the app installed on their phones?
Has someone some source regarding this idea !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push Notifications can be used for bulk conversations.  The term you want is to broadcast to a "tag".  The way to think of this is that your app will register with a Notification Hub with, say, the version of the software.  You can then target a version of the software for your broadcast.

For more information on Notification Hubs, check out the following resources:

- Notification Hubs Overview: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-overview/
- Sending to Broadcast Groups: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn530749.aspx
- Windows Phone Details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/